# how can i combine Form and digest authentication?

Tags: java, authentication

I have an application that use Form authentication. For security purposes I have to change the underlying method to digest authentication including nonce. But it seems there is no such custom solution in Java EE. Maybe I should implement digest authentication for Forms Auth. by myself. Any one can help me? 
(I'm using jdk1.7 and GlassFish 3.1.2)

edit: from [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)

> These weak cleartext protocols (Basic and Form auth.) used together with HTTPS network encryption resolve many of the threats that digest access authentication is designed to prevent.

Is it true that using HTTPS solves the problem?